# How to test Asp.Net Identity UserManger CreateAsync

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am trying to test for failure conditions of my Account controller.  When i run the test in debug mode, i am not seeing an expected result.  I am expecting to return a failed identity result when reach the line of code to create a user async.  however, in debug mode, it does not contain the error i provide it, and the success property is true.  according to this site: https://www.symbolsource.org/MyGet/Metadata/aspnetwebstacknightly/Project/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/2.0.0-rtm-140226/Release/Default/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/IdentityResult.cs?ImageName=Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, the way i am going about this it "should" work.

what is the right way to setup this test so that when i hit UserManager.CreateAsync, it will return a Failed IdentityResult?

Test i am trying to run

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task AccountController_Post_register_valid_model_account_creation_fails_returns_exception_result()
    {
        // arrange
        RegisterApiModel model = new RegisterApiModel
        {
            BusinessType = BusinessType.Architect,
            City = "asdf",
            CompanyName = "asdf",
            Email = "asdf@asdf.com",
            FirstName = "asdf",
            JobTitle = "asdf",
            LastName = "asdf",
            OperatingDistance = 123,
            Phone = "1231231234",
            Password = "12345678",
            PostalCode = "asdf",
            PrimaryContactName = "asdf",
            PrimaryContactPhone = "1231231234",
            PrimaryContactTitle = "asdf",
            StateId = 2
        };


        // create http request
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost.com/api/Account/Register");
        var route = config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}");
        var routeData = new HttpRouteData(route, new HttpRouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Companies" } });

        // mock userstore
        Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>> userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        userStore.Setup(x => x.CreateAsync(It.IsAny<ApplicationUser>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(IdentityResult.Failed("Name " + model.Email + " already exists")));
        var passwordManager = userStore.As<IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser>>();

        ApplicationUserManager um = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore.Object);
        um.PasswordValidator = pwValidator;

        AccountController controller = new AccountController(um);
        controller.ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(config, routeData, request);
        controller.Request = request;
        controller.Request.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = config;

        // act
        var result = await controller.Register(model);

        // assert
        result.ShouldBeType(typeof(ExceptionResult));
    }
```

web api method i am trying to test

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterApiModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var company = new Company
            {
                Name = model.CompanyName,
                CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                SubscriptionStatus = SubscriptionStatus.Free,
                Address1 = model.Address1 ?? string.Empty,
                Address2 = model.Address2 ?? string.Empty,
                City = model.City,
                StateId = model.StateId,
                PostalCode = model.PostalCode,
                BusinessType = model.BusinessType.Value,
                OperatingDistance = model.OperatingDistance.Value,
                Phone = PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.Phone),
                Fax = model.Fax == null ? string.Empty : PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.Fax),
                PrimaryContactName = model.PrimaryContactName,
                PrimaryContactPhone = PhoneNumber.ToStorage(model.PrimaryContactPhone),
                PrimaryContactTitle = model.PrimaryContactTitle

            };

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName, Company = company, JobTitle = model.JobTitle };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // make user a company admin
                user.Claims.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUserClaim { ClaimValue = "Admin", ClaimType = "http://bidchuck.com/company/role", UserId = user.Id });
                result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);

                    var callbackUrl = Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Account", action = "ConfirmEmail", userId = user.Id, code = code });

                    await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">link</a>");

                    return Ok();
                }
            }
            return BadRequest(result.Errors.First());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are looking on source of Identity 2.2-alpha1 - it is not released yet. Better get decompiler (I use DotPeek from Jetbrains) and decompile assemblies you use in your project.

Then you are trying to test on too high level. Extract your method into class that is independent from your controllers:

```
UserService
{
    public IdentityResult CreateUser(RegisterApiModel model, String urlCallback)
    {
        // don't forget to add generated code and userId as parameters into url
        // do your user creation.
    }
}
```

In your controller call this service:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterApiModel model)
{
    var urlCallbac = Url.Link("Default", new { controller = "Account", action = "ConfirmEmail" });
    var result = await userService.CreateUserAsync(model, urlCallback);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    return BadRequest(result.Errors.First());
}
```

And test user Service separately from controllers. Your tests will become much more simple.

And at the moment it is very difficult to say why you are getting this result. Probably mocks are not completely set up to do what's needed to be done.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'll look into a decompiler. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, DotPeek is nice because you can navigate between related classes. And it can get symbol sources from server (if available).